# App Engine Servlet Class Invoked but Code Doesn't Run

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, cron

My goal: Have a cron job run code on a servlet. The problem appears to be that when hitting the servlet on a remote server (aka it has been deployed) then I constantly get no logs and a 200 success. I'm expecting at least one of those to be true.

The cron job appears to be configured correctly. It shows on my dashboard and starts at the desired interval.

cron.xml

```
<cronentries>
<cron>
<url>/cron/cuttingScores</url>
<description>Check for the latest cutting scores and update the data store.</description>
<schedule>every 10 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
</cronentries>
```

I have two servlets defined in my web.xml, one for API code and the other for the code to run when the cron job executes.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package.RegistrationEndpoint,
                my.package.MessagingEndpoint,
                my.package.CuttingScoreEndpoint
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GAEJCronServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-classmy.package.cron.CuttingScoresCron</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GAEJCronServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cron/cuttingScores</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Locally I don't know how to run cron jobs however if I go to `localhost:8080/cron/cuttingScores` then the servlet code starts executing just fine. When I deploy the code to google's servers the cron job starts but doesn't appear to actually run the code.

Here's what my log output looks like:

```
0.1.0.1 - - [14/Sep/2015:13:13:16 -0700] "GET /cron/cuttingScores HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "erudite-bonbon-106721.appspot.com" ms=8 cpu_ms=598 queue_name=__cron task_name=546233b36b39eb25a52c51 instance=00c61b117cb0545631ed291ff941b app_engine_release=1.9.26
```

I have a lot of logs and none of them show. I even made the `doGet` method throw a runtime exception, no dice. I called `super.doGet()` also nothing! If I try to hit the url in the browser it is the same. It says alls good and fine, but the code doesn't actually run!

My servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CuttingScoresCron extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(CuttingScoresCron.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        _logger.info("In cron job get");
        if(true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("WTF I JUST WANT TO SEE THIS!");
        }
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        _logger.info("In cron job post");
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Here's my logging configuration. Keep in mind that this is the default logging configuration and I see all of my logs (info level) running locally.

logging.properties

```
.level = WARNING
```

Comment: Your log output is from the access log right? What does your logging configuration look like? Since you are getting a 200 it sounds like your logging configuration is the first thing i would look at.

Comment: I added my logging properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been deploying different "versions" from Android Studio to Google App Engine.

Apparently everything only updates when using version 1. I don't know why, but that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log at INFO level but have logging configured at the more restrictive WARN level. Modify logging.properties to set level = INFO.

Comment: Logs aren't the only problem though. In the first few lines of my doGet method there are multiple ways of throwing runtime exceptions. Neither of which get called.